# How do I freeze my code with modified library code?

Tags: python, qt, unicode, pyside, py2exe

This may be quite a newbie Python question, but no solution was found after several Googlings.

The problem is, I run into a library bug (in that library's **init**.py file) about unicode stuff. I know how to fix it, but when I did and froze my code (which import that library with modified **init**.py) with py2exe, I still get the old results (tested with some prints in **init**.py but nothing comes out of the console). However, with the same code, I can get these prints if I run my code directly (without freezing) in Python.

So my question is what happens when I freeze my code? Does **init**.py get compiled after changes or py2exe just use pre-compiled byte-code comes with library package?

Here's more information to go:
1. The library I'm talking about is PySide (1.2.1), which is a Python binding to Qt
2. The bug appears in file PySide _utils.py, line 47, when PySide trying to do a type cast from string to unicode. The string will be the location of library dlls. The problem happens when this location (or path) contains unicode chars such as Chinese characters.
3. My py2exe setup code is very simple: freeze my python code with compress 1 and optimize 2

I know I can always solve this problem by putting my freezed program in english only pathes (like system program files dir), but this would only be my last option if no better solution comes out since some users really love the 'change the installation path' option.

Thanks in advance!

---

Sorry about not providing detailed code, here it goes:

main.py: copied from a simple qt example

```
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QLabel
app = QApplication([])
window = QLabel('Window from label')
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

py2exe setup.py:

```
setup(
    options={
        "py2exe": {
            "compressed": 1,
            "optimize": 2
        }
    },
    windows=[{"script": "main.py"}]
)
```

Freeze main.py using "python setup.py py2exe" (may require msvcp90.dll) will produce an runnable exe file and many other stuffs under a folder named dist. Place that folder under some unicode path like "D:\中文\" and run the exe will reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide the necessary code change for being able to reproduce the issue.